# Character encoding that won't change the higher bits after I set them

Tags: cocoa-touch, character-encoding, bit

I'm looking for a character encoding that allows me to set a byte higher than 127. `NSASCIICharacterEncoding` and `NSUTF8CharacterEncoding` replace those higher values.

Comment: [NSUnicodeStringEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSUnicodeStringEncoding)? byte order matters once you exceed 8 bit encodings.

Comment: This one change the size of my result. I need to keep mystring like "Hello", but need to write 147 on the first bytes. NSUTF8Encoding kick out this bytes

Comment: Provide a minimal code example recreating this behavior.

Comment: I think a find NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding. It keep my byte order and string, but allow bytes to be higher than 128 ! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character encoding only matters when you're trying to interpret the bytes as characters. If that's what you need to do, and if you're using data that comes from some outside source, then use whatever encoding the outside source used.

On the other hand, if you're just trying to manage a collection of bytes (i.e. not characters), then look into using NSData instead. NSData doesn't care about character encodings, doesn't change the order of your bytes, and will happily keep track of as much data as you give it. (There's a mutable version if you need to modify the data it contains.)